# no funciona metodo get() de collections.js en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, collectionjs

Hice este código

```
function reestructurar(dir,fileA){
    var seto = new Set([]);
    read(`${dir}/training/${fileA}`, contentT => {
    for (var i = 0, chunki = contentT.split('\r\n'), leni =chunki.length; i < leni; i++){

        if(seto.get(chunki)=="") { //error
            seto.add(chunki);
        }

    }

    console.log(seto);

    });
}
```

me marca error en la funcion `get()`

estoy usando este lib http://www.collectionsjs.com/set

Comment: no funciona aun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque `chunki = contentT.split(...)` es un array. 
Debes usar dentro del get (y del add)
 como  `chunki[i]`

Aunque te recomiento usar mas bien [has()](http://www.collectionsjs.com/method/has-value) que devuelve bool

```
if(!seto.has(chunki[i]) )
    seto.add(chunki[i]);
```

Comment: funciono !!! con has() pero aun sigo sin entender porque no funciona get()

Comment: **has** comprueba si existe o no. el **get** te devuelve el elemento (en caso de haberlo igual) y además lo comparas con "" (que solo sirve si la coleccion es de Strings). Como **nota** adicional, en el enlace que pasaste , a la derecha de los metodos hay ejemplos en los que puedes usar codigo y ver que resultado te da a ti

Comment: por que restringir con esto if(!seto.has(chunki[i]) )
    seto.add(chunki[i]);  si se supone que SET no adiciona elementos repetidos?

Comment: porque tu lo tenias asi con el get. pero tienes razon. el add devuelve true si lo ha metido y false si no lo metió porque ya estaba